# Custom table join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Suppose I have 4 tables in Postgresql DB:

```
users {
 id: int
}

cars {
 id: int
}

usage_items {
 id: int,
 user_id: int,
 car_id: int,
 start: date,
 end: date
}

prices {
 id: int,
 car_id: int,
 price: int
}
```

When a user is renting a car I am creating a usage_item record to track the rental time. At the end of the month, I am sending him an invoice with calculated costs. The SQL is pretty simple here:

```
SELECT usage_items.start, usage_items.end, prices.price
FROM usage_items
JOIN prices ON prices.car_id = usage_items.car_id
```

(I omitted here WHERE clause with dates comparison, the rest of calculations I do in my Ruby code)

The problem I struggle with now is that some of my users have custom contracts with me ensuring lower prices for them. I am looking for a way to express this logic in my DB.
I came up with an idea to add user_id column to the prices table but this way I would need to create prices for every single user. So I decided to implement the following logic: if car_id in prices row is null it means that it is the default price for all the users. Otherwise, it is specific to a user. But I have no idea how to write SQL for this case, because:

```
SELECT usage_items.start, usage_items.end, prices.price
FROM usage_items
JOIN prices ON prices.car_id = usage_items.car_id
WHERE prices.user_id IS NULL OR prices.user_id = usage_items.user_id
```

returns rows for both prices. And I need only the one with an associated group or if it does not exist the one with null group_id.

Can you help me fix this SQL? Or maybe my design is bad and I should change it somehow?

Comment: I would probably create a contracts table that links the car_id to the one price record. I think it's conceptually a little simpler, plus lets you add more contract information later.

Comment: You've suddenly added a `group_id` column in your query but you haven't listed it in your table definitions or told us what it is.

Comment: @eurotrash sorry, it should be user_id, edited.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why not add a price column directly to the usage_items table? It would also take care of history calculation process if need be (ie: 2 years ago car_id has price 70 and now 72. If you were to get a report of 2 years back you wouldn't erroneously use 72 from prices now). Also doing this way handles it per usage vs per car or user.

Comment: Read "Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I like @MattS suggestion.  A contract table tied to the user (usercontracts).  that way if you have special pricing based on dates, it overrides the price record with the price listed in the contract.  In addition if pricing is limited to specific types of cars or other attributes you could have that spelled out in the contract details  Perhaps you ahve different pricing for different lengths of usage... this contract because a "Discount" of sorts.  and a that way you mantain 1 master contract for multiple users, and could have different types of contracts (Annual, Quarterly, Fleet etc)

Comment: @CetinBasoz Actually there is a start and end column on prices table in my real DB to track price changes in time. Adding price column to usage_items would be bad as it violates data redundancy rule (I can calculate this value from what I already have in my db)

Comment: No it wouldn't violate any rule, not a redundancy ever. It only makes it possible to have a particular price per usage and you get that value easily without unneeded extra tables and joins.

Comment: @CetinBasoz so when I am creating an usage_item how do I know what price should I set? Should I hardcode values in my code or keep it in a notebook next to my computer? Of course no. I still need prices table. And if I have prices table in my db I can calculate the cost for each usage item. And if I am able to calculate the value of a column you suggested it means that it is redundant.

Comment: I didn't say you don't need prices table. What I am saying is, after whatever logic you are applying and deciding the price for a "usage" (be a special price, extra discount whatever) have it recorded directly in usage_item table. In other words it covers cases of where you can calculate or not.

Comment: For example MS SQL Server has Northwind sample database (a very simple schema). There you have price in products table, but still you have the actual sale price in Order Details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your existing schema, this is one way to accomplish what you want:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE usage_items (user_id INTEGER, car_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE prices (user_id INTEGER, car_id INTEGER, price INTEGER);

INSERT INTO usage_items VALUES (1, 10), (2, 11), (3, 12);
INSERT INTO prices VALUES
    (1, 10, 101),
    (2, 11, 102),
    (4, 12, 104),
    (NULL, 10, 201),
    (NULL, 11, 202),
    (NULL, 12, 304);
```

Query (I'm not using start/end but it's the same thing):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.user_id, u.car_id) u.user_id, u.car_id, p.price
FROM usage_items u
LEFT JOIN prices p
    ON u.car_id = p.car_id
    AND (u.user_id = p.user_id OR p.user_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY u.user_id, u.car_id, CASE WHEN p.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Result:

```
| user_id | car_id | price |
| ------- | ------ | ----- |
| 1       | 10     | 101   |
| 2       | 11     | 102   |
| 3       | 12     | 304   |
```

As you can see, the records in `usage_items` with a corresponding record for their car AND user_id in `prices` get their custom price rather than the NULL version; user 3 who does not have a custom price gets the NULL version (and not the custom price for a different customer).

---

Test here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPVWEY3r22n22iKpDMrcMC/0

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!
But comments under my original question made me realize that my design is not the best here. Anyway, accepting your response as a solution :)